# How to calculate sum by comparing key value with two object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I have below two objects and i need to compare `values` object with `points` object based on the given answer like 'Q1A1' or 'Q2A1' and once key match in both object then it should return the sum of their respective answers.

```js
const values = {
    Q1: {
        Q1A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
        Q2A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q3: {
        Q3A2: "No",
    },
};

const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 0,
};
```

After comparing both above object based on the given answer the sum will be 60. So, how can i return the sum 60 by comparing these object ?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I updated my answer with a more succinct version using the values to drive the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the values to drive the script:

```js
const total = Object.values(values)
  .reduce((acc, cur) => acc + Object.entries(cur)
    .reduce((accInner, [key, val]) => val !== 'No' && points[key] ? accInner + points[key] : accInner
    , 0)
  , 0);

console.log(total)
```

```html
<script>
  const values = {
    Q1: {
      Q1A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
      Q2A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q3: {
      Q3A2: "No",
    },
  };

  const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 5, // should not be counted
  };
</script>
```

Or (easier to read) make a lookup table and filter+reduce

```js
const lookup = Object.values(values).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const [key, val] = Object.entries(cur)[0]
  if (val === "Yes") acc[key] = val;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(lookup)

const val = Object.entries(points)
  .filter(entry => lookup[entry[0]] && entry[1])
  .reduce((a, b) => a[1] + b[1]);
console.log(val)
```

```html
<script>
  const values = {
    Q1: {
      Q1A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
      Q2A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q3: {
      Q3A2: "No",
    },
  };

  const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 5, // should not be counted
  };
</script>
```

Here just looking if they key exists (based on comments)

```js
const pointKeys = [...Object.values(values).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc.add(Object.keys(cur)[0])
  return acc;
}, new Set())];

console.log(pointKeys)

const val = Object.entries(points)
  .filter(entry => pointKeys.includes(entry[0]))
  .reduce((acc,entry) => {
  console.log(entry[1])
    acc+=entry[1]
    return acc
  },0);
console.log(val)
```

```html
<script>
  const values = {
    Q1: {
      Q1A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
      Q2A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q3: {
      Q3A2: "No",
    },
  };

  const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 5, // should not be counted
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Is there any we can just compare with key and do all the maths because both same key available in object

Comment: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I was saying like Q1A1 key available in values object as well as in points object, so instead of comparing with either yes or no. Can't we just look for key if key exist in both object then we can do calculation

Comment: What is the significance of "No" or do you mean after I removed the NO

Comment: I was just asking instead of checking val is Yes or No , we can also compare with key because both key available in both object for example like Q1A1 available in values object as well as in points object. Q1A1 will always represent Yes

Comment: If you do that, you get 65 in my example. See update

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop your answers. I would suggest using `true`/`false` instead of `Yes`/`No`:

```js
const values = {
  Q1: {
    Q1A1: 'Yes'
  },
  Q2: {
    Q2A1: 'Yes'
  },
  Q3: {
    Q3A2: 'No'
  }
};

const points = {
  "Q1A1": 41,
  "Q1A2": 0,
  "Q2A1": 19,
  "Q2A2": 0,
  "Q3A1": 25,
  "Q3A2": 0
};

let total = 0;

// First loop your questions
for (const question in values) {
  // Then loop all answers in that question
  for (const [answer, value] of Object.entries(values[question])) {
    // Check if answer is 'Yes' and if that question even exists in possible question pool
    if (value == 'Yes' && points[answer] != null) {
        // Sum up total points
        total += points[answer];
    }
  }
}

alert('Your score is ' + total);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in multiple ways. Here is one :

```js
const val = Object.values(values)
  .reduce((sum, answers) => {
    sum += Object.entries(answers)
      .reduce((subSum, [answer, value]) => {
        if(value === 'No') return subSum;
        return subSum + points[answer]
       }, 0);
    return sum;
  }, 0);

console.log(val);
```

```html
<script>
  const values = {
    Q1: {
      Q1A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q2: {
      Q2A1: "Yes",
    },
    Q3: {
      Q3A2: "No",
    },
  };

  const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 0,
  };
</script>
```

Comment: You're right, I added it

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```js
 arr_points.includes(Object.keys(value).join('')) && Object.values(value).join('') === 'Yes'

                    ?accumulator +  points[Object.keys(value).join('')]
    
                    :accumulator
```

```js
const values = {
    Q1: {
        Q1A1: 'Yes'
    },
    Q2: {
        Q2A1: 'Yes'
    },
    Q3: {
        Q3A2: 'No'
    },
    Q4:{ QE:'No'}
}
const points = {
    Q1A1: 41,
    Q1A2: 0,
    Q2A1: 19,
    Q2A2: 0,
    Q3A1: 25,
    Q3A2: 0
}
const arr_points = Object.keys(points)
//
const Sum  = Object.entries(values).reduce((accumulator,[key, value]) => 
                    arr_points.includes(Object.keys(value).join('')) && Object.values(value).join('') === 'Yes'

                    ?accumulator +  points[Object.keys(value).join('')]
    
                    :accumulator
        
, 0 )

console.log(Sum)
```